How to correctly pass FFMPEG arguments using PYTHON?
I wrote script to create a hardcoded overlay onto a video from a .txt data file using this command syntax:
ffmpeg -i 'input.mp4' -vf "ass='subfile.ass'" -c:v h264_qsv 'output.mp4'
If I do this, it works fine (please note there are no white spaces in path):
import subprocess
ffmpeg_loc = 'c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg'
video = 'c:/temp/UTP20/v.mp4'
assfile = 'c:/temp/UTP20/v.ass'
output = 'c:/temp/UTP20/r.mp4'
assfile = assfile.replace(':', '\\\\:') #escaping colon for filter
command = '{} -i {} -vf "ass={}" -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast -profile:v high -b:v {}M {}'.format(ffmpeg_loc,video, assfile, 3, output)
print(command)
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                  stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL)

out, err = p.communicate()
print('OUT:')
print(err.decode())



Now, if there are white spaces it doesn't (ie path is c:/temp/UTP 20):
[in#0 @ 0000023ae8c71a40] Error opening input: No such file or directory
Error opening input file c:/temp/UTP.
Error opening input files: No such file or directory

From FFMPEG doc (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html), looks like single quotes can be used to pass file names, so I modified my command like this:
command = '{} -i \'{}\' -vf "ass={}" -c:v h264_qsv -preset veryfast -profile:v high -b:v {}M \'{}\''.format(ffmpeg_loc,video, assfile, 3, output)

But I still have the same error. However, if I copy the printed command, and paste it in a shell, it does work.
So, instead of a string command, I tried string array with no filter for test (please note: there's no need of single quoting filename, even if it contains white spaces):
command = [ffmpeg_loc,'-i',video,'-c:v','h264_qsv','-preset','slow','-profile:v','high','-b:v','3M',output]

This is working. Now if I add the filter:
command = [ffmpeg_loc,'-i',video, '-vf', '"ass={}"'.format(assfile), '-c:v','h264_qsv','-preset','slow','-profile:v','high','-b:v','3M',output]

print(' '.join(command) #to see the passed command

Produces this error:
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000029403aa1040] No option name near 'c\:/temp/UTP 20/v.ass"'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000029403aa1040] Error parsing a filter description around: 
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000029403aa1040] Error parsing filterchain '"ass=c\\:/temp/UTP 20/v.ass"' around: 
[vost#0:0/h264_qsv @ 0000029403de2ac0] Error initializing a simple filtergraph

I can't find a solution to make a command working with both filters and whitespaces.
What am I doing wrong ?
I use Visual Studio Code, Windows 10, Python 3.9.6 and the latest release of FFMPEG
EDIT
I didn't manage to use list as input for subprocess, and not did manage to get subtitles using ffmpeg-python.
However, this works (filter works fine in a single string, and filename with spaces are supported if filemane is double quoted)
import subprocess

ffmpeg_loc = 'c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg'
video = 'c:/temp/UTP 20/v.mp4'
assfile = 'c:/temp/UTP 20/v.ass'
output = 'c:/temp/UTP 20/r.mp4'
assfile = assfile.replace(':', '\\\\:')
cmd ='{} -hide_banner -i "{}" -vf "ass={}" -c:v h264_qsv "{}"'.format(ffmpeg_loc, video, assfile, output)
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print("ERR:")
print( err.decode())

If using this list, it doesn't work (error opening input file):
cmd=[ffmpeg_loc, '-hide_banner', '-i', '"{}"'.format(video), '-vf', '"ass={}"'.format(assfile),'-c:v', 'h264_qsv', '"{}"'.format(output)]


It will be easier to just pass the command-line arguments pre-parsed as a list - see the linked duplicate, which covers all techniques. Your idea there was correct - the problem is that when you add the '-vf', '"ass={}"'.format(assfile) arguments, you're substituting in an assflle value where you substituted in a backslash-escape that was meant to work with the shell's parsing of command-line arguments, but you aren't using that any more so you shouldn't include that escape. This could reasonably be considered a typo, given that the error message is already showing you the problem.

There is ffmpeg-python, a dedicated library for making command line parameters for ffmpeg! If you want to do complicated stuff, it might be more powerful and less confusing.

@KarlKnechtel: I'm not sure I fully understand (No irony, I actually DON'T understand). Do you mean that I do not need to escape the colon ? I tried this (and many other varations), with no success: command = [ffmpeg_loc,'-i',video, '-vf', '"ass=c:/temp/UTP 20/v.ass"', '-c:v','h264_qsv','-preset','slow','-profile:v','high','-b:v','3M',output]

@anatolyg Thanks for the suggestion, it is indeed very nice. However, I can't get it to work:(ffmpeg  .input(video)  .filter('subtitles',assfile )  .output(output, vcodec='h264_qsv', preset='fast', **{'b:v':'3M'})  .run()) returns Failed to set value '[0]subtitles=c\\\:/temp/UTP 20/v.ass[s0]' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument

In this case, I strongly recommend that you debug the command line that you want to use at the command line first, and then figure out how that translates into Python. If you run into a specific issue in that translation, that isn't covered by the linked duplicate, you may have a suitable question.

maybe you should put text in " " instead of ' ' and then you may safely use ' inside text  "ass='...'"

@KarlKnechtel
That's how I started, using ffmpeg in command line is OK. That was indeed a translation problem.

try `'f"ass='{assfile}'" (FFmpeg parser uses single quotes to define a contiguous string).

I tried this, it doesn't work. Filter must be double quoted : "ass=filename". '"ass={}"'.format(assfile) in a list produces the same output as in '{} -hide_banner -i "{}" -vf "ass={}" -c:v h264_qsv  "{}"'.format(ffmpeg_loc, video, assfile, output). I just don't get why it doesn't work. Tried '"ass=\'{}\'"'.format(assfile) which produces a single quoted filename in a double quoted filter, with no luck. There's definitely something strange with either the way subprocess.Popen creates a command from a list, or, most likely, FFmpeg parser.
